# server.tomcat.baseDir property not working correctly after I migrated Spring Boot 1.5.22 to 2.0.0

Tags: spring, tomcat

I have migrated Spring Boot 1.5.22 to 2.0.0 and I have an issue when it comes to the embedded Tomcat generating the temporary directories.

My application.properties is looking like this:

basePath=/info/components
server.tomcat.baseDir=${basePath}/apps/service

And I have a class which is called right before  starting the spring boot app and overrides the basePath based on what environment is running on.

My application.properties used for development looks like this:

basePath=classpath:

The class looks like this:

```
public class BasePathOverride extends PathInit {

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationContext context) throws InitException {
        String basePath = context.getEnvironment().getProperty("basePath");

        if (//check if basePath is empty) {
            String path = getAbsolutePath(basePath); -> returns the absolute path ("/home/user/..")

            // check if the new path is correct/exists

            System.setProperty("basePath", path);
        } else {
            ..
        }
    }

}
```

This class is an Initilizer class and PathInit provides the getAbsolutePath() method.

The problem is that, after overriding the basePath value used by the app, the tomcat base dir is still written to /info/components.

This code works ok for the Spring Boot 1.5.22 version.

I have investigated the problem and it seems to be the spring boot 2.0 version upgrade

UPDATE:
The issue was solved after upgrading the spring boot version from 2.0.0.RELEASE to 2.0.9.RELEASE.

Comment: I don't think this is related to spring boot 2.0 version upgrade. Can you share some links that indicate that the problem is actually the Spring boot version?

Comment: I don't have an actual link. I did some reverse engineering for the Spring Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE and saw that the workflow of creating the embedded tomcat web server suffered some changes. I solved the issue by upgrading the Spring boot version from 2.0.0.RELEASE to 2.0.9.RELEASE.